# Difference between Bean creation and initialization while using @Lazy

Tags: spring

Spring IOC creates and initializes beans on start up. What is the difference here between creation and initialization of bean?

While using @Lazy, it is said that, bean annotated with @Lazy will be instantiated lazily. Does that mean, the bean will be created[like other beans not annotated with @Lazy] on ApplicationContext start up and just initializes when first referenced?

Comment: I answered a similar question recently. You can check if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924075/whats-the-difference-between-lazy-annotation-and-lazy-init-attribute-of-bean/53925100#53925100

Answer (score -1):

**@Lazy**

Indicates whether a bean is to be lazily initialized.
May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with @Component or on methods annotated with @Bean.

If this annotation is not present on a @Component or @Bean definition, eager initialization will occur. If present and set to true, the @Bean or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory. If present and set to false, the bean will be instantiated on startup by bean factories that perform eager initialization of singletons.

If Lazy is present on a @Configuration class, this indicates that all @Bean methods within that @Configuration should be lazily initialized. If @Lazy is present and false on a @Bean method within a @Lazy-annotated @Configuration class, this indicates overriding the 'default lazy' behavior and that the bean should be eagerly initialized.

In addition to its role for component initialization, this annotation may also be placed on injection points marked with Autowired or Inject: In that context, it leads to the creation of a lazy-resolution proxy for all affected dependencies, as an alternative to using ObjectFactory or Provider.